# change and set visible field of smarttable using javascript in ui5

Tags: sapui5

i want to change the initially visible fields of smartTable to other fields which are not initially visible or (make other invisible fields visible in table column) using javascript so that we don't need to set it using ui.

i have tried calling setInitiallyVisibleFields but it gives error saying ,it can't be changed once table is initialized

Comment: Like fabiopagoti answered. But the better way is instead of using setVisible method I would use a model and set it in XML view. If you want to switch visibility of the table modify the model value from false to true and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Just use [setVisible method from sap.ui.core.Control class](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/setVisible).

1. Give your SmartTable an ID
2. Capture it inside your controller using `this.byId`
3. call setVisible(true/false)

Comment: soory , but i don't want to make table invisible . i want to change the visible fields out multiple that we have available say i have 20 fields but initial visible are 5 fields and i want to change with 10 other different fields

Comment: Why not using annotations?